# find equation of tangent and normal to the hyperbola

Tags: calculus

find equation of tangent and normal of the hyperbola $\dfrac {X^2}{a^2} - \dfrac {Y^2}{b^2} = 1\;$  at the point ($X_0 , Y_0$ ).. find the equation of tangent and normal .

Answer (score 1):

Our hyperbola has equation
$$\frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1.$$
We want $\frac{dy}{dx}$. Use **implicit differentiation.** We get
$$\frac{2x}{a^2}-\frac{2y}{b^2}\frac{dy}{dx}=0.\tag{1}$$
Now we can find $\frac{dy}{dx}$ at our point $(x_0,y_0)$. That gives the slope of the tangent line, and now we can find the equation of the tangent line.

The slope of the **normal** is $-\frac{1}{m}$, where $m$ is the slope of the tangent. So now we know the slope of the normal. It passes through $(x_0,y_0)$, so we can find its equation.

**Remark:** For the normal, there is a minor complication if $x_0=\pm a$ (and therefore $y_0=0$).  In those two cases, the normal is vertical.

**Added:** There seems to be difficulty in finding the equation of the tangent line. From (1) we have $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{2xb^2}{2ya^2}$. So at the point $(x_0,y_0)$ on the hyperbola, the slope of the tangent line is equal to $\frac{x_0b^2}{y_0a^2}$.

It follows that the equation of the tangent line is 
$$\frac{y-y_0}{x-x_0}=\frac{x_0 b^2}{y_0a^2}.$$ 
Now we do some algebraic manipulation. Multiply through by $(x-x_0)(y_0a^2)$. We get 
$$(y-y_0)y_0a^2=(x-x_0)(x_0b^2).$$
This simplifies to 
$$xx_0b^2 -yy_0a^2=x_0^2b^2-y_0^2a^2.$$
Divide through by $a^2b^2$, and use the fact that $\frac{x_0^2}{a^2}-\frac{y_0^2}{b^2}=1$. We end up with
$$\frac{xx_0}{a^2}-\frac{yy_0}{b^2}=1.$$

Answer (score 0):

Just let $F(x,y) = \dfrac {x^2}{a^2} - \dfrac {y^2}{b^2}$. Then $\nabla = \left( \dfrac {2x}{a^2}, \dfrac {-2y}{b^2}\right)$.

The tangent line is $\dfrac {2x_0}{a^2(x - x_0)} - \dfrac {2y_0}{b^2(y - y_0)} = 0$.

You already know how to find the normal because you can just invert the slope (swap the components in the gradient), but don't forget the $-$ sign

Comment: could you explain how you found out the gradient of $F(x,y) = \dfrac {x^2}{a^2} - \dfrac {y^2}{b^2}$ to be $\nabla = \left( \dfrac {2x}{a^2}, \dfrac {-2y}{b^2}\right)$ ? This seems to be a shorter method to find the slope instead of calculating $\frac{dy}{dx}$ using implicit differentiation as André did in his answer